# ABP Framework: What is the best practice to handle entity parent with entities childs?

Tags: abp

I recently use ABP Framework (6.0), and I create a "DemoApp" application for explain my problem: https://github.com/KevinAlvesGroupeBRIAND/DemoApp

I have two classes in `Domain` layer:

```cs
    // Company.cs
    public class Company : FullAuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
    {
        public virtual string Code { get; set; }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Site> Sites { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
    //Site.cs
    public class Site : FullAuditedEntity<Guid>
    {
        protected Site()
        {
        }

        public Site(Guid id) : base(id)
        {
        }

        public virtual Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        public virtual string Code { get; set; }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

*(Note: Perhaps constructors are useless in Site class)*

In `Application.Contracts` layer, I write DTO classes:

- CompanyDto.cs
- CreateCompanyDto.cs
- UpdateCompanyDto.cs
- SiteOfCompanyDto.cs (related to CompanyDto class)
- SiteOfCreateCompanyDto.cs (related to CreateCompanyDto class)
- SiteOfUpdateCompanyDto.cs (related to UpdateCompanyDto class)

Also, I have a service class in `Application` layer:

```cs
 public class CompanyService : ApplicationService, ICompanyService
    {
        private readonly ICompanyRepository _companyRepository;

        public CompanyService(ICompanyRepository companyRepository)
        {
            _companyRepository = companyRepository;
        }

        public async Task<CompanyDto> CreateAsync(CreateCompanyDto input)
        {
            var entity = ObjectMapper.Map<CreateCompanyDto, Company>(input);
            entity = await _companyRepository.InsertAsync(entity);
            return ObjectMapper.Map<Company, CompanyDto>(entity);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<CompanyDto>> CreateCompaniesAsync(IEnumerable<CreateCompanyDto> input)
        {
            var entities = ObjectMapper.Map<IEnumerable<CreateCompanyDto>, IEnumerable<Company>>(input);
            await _companyRepository.InsertManyAsync(entities);
            return ObjectMapper.Map<IEnumerable<Company>, IEnumerable<CompanyDto>>(entities);
        }

        public async Task DeleteAsync(Guid id)
        {
            await _companyRepository.DeleteAsync(id);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<CompanyDto>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            var entities = await _companyRepository.GetListAsync(includeDetails: true);
            return ObjectMapper.Map<IEnumerable<Company>, IEnumerable<CompanyDto>>(entities);
        }

        public async Task<CompanyDto> GetAsync(Guid id)
        {
            var entity = await _companyRepository.GetAsync(id, includeDetails: true);
            return ObjectMapper.Map<Company, CompanyDto>(entity);
        }

        public async Task<CompanyDto> GetByCodeAsync(string code)
        {
            var entity = await _companyRepository.GetAsync(o => o.Code == code, includeDetails: true);
            return ObjectMapper.Map<Company, CompanyDto>(entity);
        }

        public async Task<CompanyDto> UpdateAsync(Guid id, UpdateCompanyDto input)
        {
            var entity = await _companyRepository.GetAsync(id, includeDetails: true);
            entity = ObjectMapper.Map(input, entity);
            entity = await _companyRepository.UpdateAsync(entity);
            return ObjectMapper.Map<Company, CompanyDto>(entity);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<CompanyDto>> UpdateCompaniesAsync(IDictionary<Guid, UpdateCompanyDto> input)
        {
            var entities = await _companyRepository.GetListAsync(o => input.Keys.Contains(o.Id));
            entities = ObjectMapper.Map(input.Values, entities);
            await _companyRepository.UpdateManyAsync(entities);
            return ObjectMapper.Map<IEnumerable<Company>, IEnumerable<CompanyDto>>(entities);
        }
    }
```

When I execute tests, I get this error:
`System.InvalidOperationException : The instance of entity type 'Site' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.`

[image: See results here]

I read many documentations in ABP site web, but I don't understand what is the best practice when I have a entity with child collection:

- https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Entities#entities-with-guid-keys
- https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/8645
- https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/7980
- https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/12933

Can you explain to me what is advised to write the service and DTO classes?

Thanks.

---

**ANSWER TO @Ahmad Masoum:**
Github branch : https://github.com/KevinAlvesGroupeBRIAND/DemoApp/tree/master_comment130681517_74011950

After testing your recommandation, `Site` class implements `AuditedEntity` instead of `FullAuditedEntity`.

```cs
    public class Site : AuditedEntity<Guid> {
      //...
    }
```

I pass a new tests and I have this results:
[image: New results here]

As we can see, `Should_Update_Company` is OK, but I have always the same error for `Should_Create_Company`, `Should_Create_Companies` and `Should_Update_Companies`.

Comment: Can you change your entities to `Audited` instead of `FullAudited` and check if you still have the same problem or not?

Comment: i think this happens on `UpdateAsync` When you get an entity with details in the case of `FullAudited`

Comment: I Faced this error multiple times, It happens when you have two `FullAduited` entities with navigation properties used with `ObjectMapper`. if you remove `ObjectMapper` and update all the values manually it should work. I don't know why this happens I posted an issue on GitHub but didn't get response

Comment: I'll keep looking, this problem is still weird.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not initializing the sub-collection (`ICollection<Site>`) of the **Company** class. This might be the cause of this problem.

```cs
    // Company.cs
    public class Company : FullAuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
    {
        public virtual string Code { get; set; }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Site> Sites { get; set; }

        public Company(Guid id) : base(id)
        {
           Sites = new Collection<Site>(); //initialize the collection
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tested your suggestion, but I have the same error. Github branch: https://github.com/KevinAlvesGroupeBRIAND/DemoApp/tree/master_comment74013212_74011950